# arrow functions in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im sharing information between two components in vue. In this moment I can get the value the created hook with an arrow function but, I cant asing this value for other property that I declared. I read that arrow functions doesnt work in created hook, I want to know how can I replace this arrow function and get the value that I need.

```
    data() {
        return{
        userloged:'',
        }
    },
    created(){
        serverBus.$on('validation', (user) =>{
            this.userloged = user
            console.log("Changed userloged", this.userloged)
            console.log("Here is the user", user) 
            return this.userloged})
    },
```

userloged is my property declared.

Comment: There are no arrow functions in that code.

Comment: created(){
            serverBus.$on('validation', (user) =>{
                this.userloged = user
                console.log("Changed userloged", this.userloged)
                console.log("Here is the user", user) 
                return this.userloged})
        },

Comment: This question needs a bit more code and clarification. Also, if you mention using arrow functions as the question, make sure to include it in the question.

Comment: I changed the question to include the arrow function. When I make the log in the created hook I can get the value for user and asign it to userloged but, If I log the value for userloged in other method this property is empty.

Comment: Does `userloged` exist on `this` *before* this event occurs? If not, [this will not work properly](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). If it *does* then this code is fine.

Comment: Please share what those console logs printing and console errors

Comment: "this" in arrow function points to parent in ES6

Comment: @Bert I changed the code to show you that I declared userloged in data, but doesnt work.

Comment: yes @Bert I agree, but I dont know how can I declare userloged. I tried something, I put userloged outside of the arrow function and asign a value and this works. `        created(){
            this.userloged='Camila'
        },`

Comment: It should work; here is an example. I expect the error is somewhere else. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pVLxWR?editors=1010

Comment: this.userloged  in arrow function as callback has context of vue component context , as this in arrow function in this case refers to created method Context

Comment: Also, just because it makes me feel better, whenever you subscribe to an event on an event bus in Vue, you should remember to unsubscribe when  the component is destroyed (because Vue will not do it automatically). Here is an example of that. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zjWmpR?editors=1010

Comment: @Bert you are the best!! thank you so much! it works!

Answer (score 1):

From [Vue's official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html):

> Don’t use arrow functions on an options property or callback, such as `created: () => console.log(this.a)` [...]. Since arrow functions are bound to the parent context, `this` will not be the Vue instance as you’d expect, often resulting in errors such as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined`.

It's hard to see how to be sure to remove all bugs without having access to a [minimal example that reproduces the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but replacing `(user) =>` by `function(user)` should already remove the main bugs.

Answer (score 0):

1. What "Don't use arrow function" really means is that you have to define the `create` callback like this:

```
created () {...} // good
```

but not this:

```
created: () => {...} // bad, do not use
```

because in the second example `this` is bound to global but not your Vue instance, so `this.userloged` will not work.

2. The key point of the problem is that you are using arrow functions INSIDE an instance method, which, for your question, `serverBus.$on`. So here `this` inside the arrow function actually binds to `serverBus`.

what you will want to do is shift `this` to something like `that` before entering the arrow function, like this:

```
created () {
  const that = this
  serverBus.$on('validation', (user) =>{
    that.userloged = user
    console.log("Changed userloged", that.userloged)
    console.log("Here is the user", user) 
    return that.userloged
  })
}
```